# how to create a dropdown attribute for product with dynamic options M2

Tags: magento2, product-attribute

I want to create a new attribute product with dynamic options that comes from custom tables then i want to edit my product and make it configurable according to this attribute how to proceed thanks in advance 
updated question

```
`<?php


 namespace Mdweb\ConfigAttribute\Model\Config\Source;

 use Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\OptionFactory;
 use Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table;


 class Options extends 
 \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\AbstractSource
 {
/**
 * @var OptionFactory
 */
protected $optionFactory;
protected $registry;
protected $prixchoix;
protected $colchoix;
/**
 * @var \BO\Choix\Model\Choix
 */
protected $_choice;


/**
 * @param OptionFactory $optionFactory
 */
public function __construct(OptionFactory $optionFactory, \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
                            \BO\Prix\Model\Prix $choixprix,
                            \BO\Choix\Model\Choix $choix)
{
    //you can use this if you want to prepare options dynamically

    $this->optionFactory = $optionFactory;
    $this->registry = $registry;
    $this->prixchoix = $choixprix;
    $this->_choice = $choix;
}

/**
 * Get all options
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function toOptionArray()
{

    $_product = $this->registry->registry('current_product');

    $_sku = $_product->getSku();
    if (isset($_sku)) {

        $var1 = substr($_sku, 0, 1);


        $var2 = substr($_sku, 1, 2);

        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $resource = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
        $connection = $resource->getConnection();
        $tableName = $resource->getTableName('table_prix');


        $fields = array('prix_unitaire');


        $sql = $connection->select()
            ->from($tableName, $fields)
            ->where('code_famille' . '=?', $var1)
            ->where('code_nom_commercial' . '=?', $var2)
            ->join('table_choix',
                'table_choix.choix_id = table_prix.code_choix',
                [
                    'designation_choix'
                ]);

        $result = $connection->fetchAll($sql);

        if ($result) {
            $i = 0;
            foreach ($result as $elt) {
                $this->_options[$i] = ['label' => " Choix" . $elt['designation_choix'] . "-" . $elt['prix_unitaire'] . "£", 'value' => " Choix" . $elt['designation_choix'] . "-" . $elt['prix_unitaire'] . "£"];
                $i++;
            }


        }





    }
    else {
        $this->_options = [['label' => __('No'), 'value' => '0'], ['label' => __('Yes'), 'value' => '1'], ['label' => __('Other'), 'value' => '2']];
    }
    return $this->_options;
}

public function getAllOptions()
{
    return $this->toOptionArray();
}
/**
 * Get a text for option value
 *
 * @param string|integer $value
 * @return string|bool
 */
public function getOptionText($value)
{
    foreach ($this->getAllOptions() as $option) {
        if ($option['value'] == $value) {
            return $option['label'];
        }
    }
    return false;
}
}`
```

and here is my installData

```
<?php

 namespace Mdweb\ConfigAttribute\Setup;

 use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
 use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory /* For Attribute create  */;
 use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
 use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
 use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

 /**
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
 class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
 {
/**
 * EAV setup factory
 *
 * @var EavSetupFactory
 */
private $eavSetupFactory;
/**
 * Init
 *
 * @param EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
 */
public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
{
    $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;

}

public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
{

    $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

    $eavSetup->removeAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,'choix_prix_product');
    $eavSetup->addAttribute(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
        'choix_prix_product',/* Custom Attribute Code */
        [
            'type' => 'text',/* Data type in which formate your value save in database*/
            'backend' => '',
            'frontend' => '',
            'label' => 'Choix-Prix de vente', /* lablel of your attribute*/
            'input' => 'select',
            'class' => '',
            'source' => 'Mdweb\ConfigAttribute\Model\Config\Source\Options',
            /* Source of your select type custom attribute options*/
            'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
            /*Scope of your attribute */
            'visible' => true,
            'required' => false,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'default' => '',
            'searchable' => false,
            'filterable' => false,
            'comparable' => false,
            'visible_on_front' => false,
            'used_in_product_listing' => false,
            'unique' => false,
            'option' => [ // temporary
                'values' => [
                ],
            ],
        ]
    );
}
}
```

i can see the options of the attribute for existing product and for the new i can see static attribute but when i access stores->attribute 
[image]

so i can't make my product config according to this attribute

Comment: Using programmatically?

Answer (score 3):

You can create options for select element while creating the attribute.

Let's take an example:

> app/code/Namespace/Modulename/Setup/InstallData.php

```
<?php
namespace Namespace\Modulename\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    /**
     * EAV setup factory
     *
     * @var EavSetupFactory
     */
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    /**
     * Init
     *
     * @param EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
     */
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        /**
         * Add attributes to the eav_attribute
         */
        $eavSetup->removeAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY, 'product_select_attribute');
        $eavSetup->removeAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY, 'product_custom_attribute');

        $statusOptions = 'Namespace\Modulename\Model\Config\Source\StatusOptions';
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
            'product_select_attribute',
            [
                'group' => 'Custom Product Attribute',
                'type' => 'int',
                'backend' => '',
                'frontend' => '',
                'label' => 'Product Status',
                'input' => 'select',
                'class' => '',
                'source' => $statusOptions,
                'global' => ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
                'visible' => true,
                'required' => false,
                'user_defined' => false,
                'default' => '',
                'searchable' => false,
                'filterable' => false,
                'comparable' => false,
                'is_used_in_grid' => true,
                'visible_on_front' => false,
                'used_in_product_listing' => true,
                'unique' => false
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

In above code i used  `'source' => $statusOptions,` it is defind select option dynamically.

You need to create Model file for define our custom option of select box, `$statusOptions = ‘Namespace\Modulename\Model\Config\Source\StatusOptions’;`

Create **StatusOptions.php** file under Model and define our enable and disable option value. **(Use below code for static value)**

> app/code/Namespace/Modulename/Model/Config/Source/StatusOptions.php

```
<?php
namespace Namespace\Modulename\Model\Config\Source;

use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\AbstractSource;

class StatusOptions extends AbstractSource
{
    /**
     * Get all options
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getAllOptions()
    {
        if (null === $this->_options) {
            $this->_options=[
                                ['label' => __('Enable'), 'value' => 1],
                                ['label' => __('Disable'), 'value' => 0]
                            ];
        }
        return $this->_options;
    }
}
```

---

**(Use below code for dynamic value)**

Change below function code for dynamic data

```
public function getAllOptions()
{
    $collection = $this->CollectionFactory->create();
    foreach ($collection as $item) {
        $this->_options[] = [
                'label' => __($item['title']),
                'value' => $item['id'],
            ];
    }

    return $this->_options;
}
```

Run below command :

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade
>
> php bin/magento cache:flush
>
> php bin/magento indexer:reindex

I hope it helps!

Comment: thanks for your replay but i diid that but i got  error i will put my code please check it

Comment: share your error & code.

Comment: please check my uodated question

Comment: share your error for better understand

Comment: i do shared the error

Comment: please check the updated question

Comment: I can see the only code. not error.

Comment: the picture iin the end

Comment: a white page with this message Manage Swatch (Values of Your Attribute)

Is Default Swatch Admin Default Store View

Comment: there is no error in the console

Comment: In image, it is displaying no output value. and without specific error, it is difficult to debug.

Comment: so what do you advice me

Comment: why i diid not find the detailed page of the attribute

Comment: do i miss some details

Comment: they advised me to put the options static and then change them with a plugin can you help me with this idea please

Comment: the problem is that in fisrt time this attributes do not have options but after the creation of product  this attribute will take options according to a custom table that change according to the name of product